# Encrypt a file and share between computers

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs

I started using LastPass and after a few months [a bug](https://forums.lastpass.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=268795) started and has me re-thinking my move from storing my files in [an encrypted folder](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ecryptfs.html) on my computers. You can see from the link the bug isn't dangerous on the surface, just inconvenient and unresolved since the beginning of August.

I'd consider switching to one of the other many password managers like 1password, keepersecurity, kaspersky password manager or others but I'd rather not be tied to a online 3rd party password manager and hoping there's never a breach.

The biggest problem with using the encrypted folder method is at least 1 or more computers needs to be updated manually each time I add a site, note or update a password.

For something more robust than a text file I'd consider using [keepassx](https://github.com/keepassx/keepassx) but it looks like it's [not under active development](https://github.com/keepassx/keepassx/pull/204) and has severe [unresolved bugs](https://dev.keepassx.org/projects/keepassx/issues?set_filter=1&sort=priority%3Adesc%2Cid%3Adesc&tracker_id=1). So I considered moving to the fork [keypassxc](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc) which is active but has [many unresolved issues](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/issues). Sync to external file is still a [waiting to be implemented](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/issues/90) with keypassxc.

Ideally it would be great if i could create a encrypted file in my private directory, have all changes, synced (maybe by a symbolic link) to a shared folder, but only readable by a program (maybe with [nodejs crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html)) on the host that has the ciphers and user supplied password.

Does any script or program already do this on Ubuntu?